# forwarding /var/usr/emails/dave to other emails

Tags: email, shell, opensuse, forwarding

I'm new to openSuse 11.1, I have several crontab jobs running, one of which creates a dynamic list of 'at' jobs each day. I've noticed every time one of the 'at' jobs finish, an email is sent to /var/usr/emails/dave.

Is there anyway I can have these emails forwarded to other email addresses?

Comment: Where exactly are those "other" emails located? `~/Mail`? Gmail's  inbox? `/var/mail/dave`?

Comment: Sorry have edited question, meant to say email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `sendmail`-compatible MTA, crond will use it to send mail, like most other Unix programs do.

If you want to forward everything to an "outside" mailbox, you need to install a MTA. For a server, I prefer `postfix` - but there also are `exim4` and the old `sendmail`, after which that binary was named.

For a personal computer, where you don't need incoming mail, you can get [`esmtp`](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/) - it relays mail through an external SMTP server, such as Gmail's or your ISP's. (You probably will need to get a MDA such as `procmail` or `maildrop` and configure esmtp for it. It's still more lightweight than having five `postfix` daemons running.)

Then, create a file `~/.forward` with your real email address in it, and everything should be forwarded there.

---

*`/var/usr/emails/$USER` is quite an unusual place to store mail... for me, at least.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer exactly what i'm looking for. :-)

No emails are stored here, a file is created, a report from /bin/sh when it finishs any execution of scripts, this file contains any print statements from my 'at' jobs, helping me to get feedback. Thought it would be nice to have this file forwarded to me when i'm not at the desk.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the .forward file might be your friend. Or set up a mail account in your favorite mailbrowser for local mail access for maintainance